# SQLalchemy select minimum value per period

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

My problem.
I have flask application using sqlalchemy and sqlite3.
I have data in a table in sqlite3 defined as follows

```
CREATE TABLE pathloss (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    timestamp DATETIME,
    value FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

with data example :

```
221516|2022-03-23 08:30:05.294763|236.82
221517|2022-03-23 08:30:20.940485|236.46
221518|2022-03-23 08:30:31.232806|237.74
221519|2022-03-23 08:30:41.557013|236.62
221520|2022-03-23 08:30:51.858161|234.96
221521|2022-03-23 08:31:02.176718|233.12
221522|2022-03-23 08:31:12.528831|234.8
221523|2022-03-23 08:31:24.665252|235.53
221524|2022-03-23 08:32:00.677398|235.61
221525|2022-03-23 08:32:46.292968|235.68
221526|2022-03-23 08:33:08.064290|233.71
221527|2022-03-23 08:33:19.905184|235.38
221528|2022-03-23 08:33:32.668282|235.22
221529|2022-03-23 08:33:42.987208|237.19
221530|2022-03-23 08:33:53.302518|235.14
221531|2022-03-23 08:34:11.864812|235.54
221532|2022-03-23 08:35:00.794551|235.18
221533|2022-03-23 08:35:12.851588|235.43
221534|2022-03-23 08:35:24.494199|234.89
221535|2022-03-23 08:36:08.627040|234.0
221536|2022-03-23 08:36:26.548283|234.07
221537|2022-03-23 08:36:37.919230|234.37
221538|2022-03-23 08:36:53.891550|233.26
221539|2022-03-23 08:37:05.871792|232.21
221540|2022-03-23 08:37:16.213301|233.36
221541|2022-03-23 08:37:26.492268|232.75
221542|2022-03-23 08:37:38.375853|232.05
221543|2022-03-23 08:37:51.172715|231.55
221544|2022-03-23 08:38:01.526706|231.17
221545|2022-03-23 08:38:11.801171|227.22
221546|2022-03-23 08:38:24.068011|229.62
221547|2022-03-23 08:38:38.054712|234.2
221548|2022-03-23 08:39:31.895501|233.53
221549|2022-03-23 08:39:57.695307|232.52
221550|2022-03-23 08:40:15.447165|232.47
221551|2022-03-23 08:40:32.277798|231.74
221552|2022-03-23 08:40:47.157171|227.93
221553|2022-03-23 08:41:01.781600|228.99
221554|2022-03-23 08:41:16.873229|227.44
221555|2022-03-23 08:41:31.643615|227.77
221556|2022-03-23 08:41:46.544188|228.7
221557|2022-03-23 08:42:01.975447|228.88
221558|2022-03-23 08:42:17.085603|231.54
221559|2022-03-23 08:42:31.508930|234.36
221560|2022-03-23 08:42:46.469516|232.06
221561|2022-03-23 08:43:01.784301|233.54
221562|2022-03-23 08:43:17.072994|236.22
221563|2022-03-23 08:43:32.083951|234.38
221564|2022-03-23 08:43:46.879787|231.8
221565|2022-03-23 08:44:01.790349|232.41
221566|2022-03-23 08:44:16.456424|230.83
221567|2022-03-23 08:44:31.697554|233.99
221568|2022-03-23 08:44:47.039657|233.75
221569|2022-03-23 08:45:01.629946|235.14
221570|2022-03-23 08:45:16.809688|233.25
221571|2022-03-23 08:45:27.112430|236.15
221572|2022-03-23 08:45:37.395134|232.63
221573|2022-03-23 08:45:47.686103|236.23
221574|2022-03-23 08:45:57.972811|234.02
221575|2022-03-23 08:46:10.114894|231.36
221576|2022-03-23 08:46:20.400897|234.35
221577|2022-03-23 08:46:30.727899|233.14
221578|2022-03-23 08:46:41.053248|232.51
221579|2022-03-23 08:46:51.342453|233.96
221580|2022-03-23 08:47:01.678473|232.56
221581|2022-03-23 08:47:12.005399|233.97
221582|2022-03-23 08:47:22.328787|235.98
221583|2022-03-23 08:47:32.646055|236.2
221584|2022-03-23 08:47:42.931063|231.4
221585|2022-03-23 08:47:53.219864|230.0
221586|2022-03-23 08:48:03.514733|229.96
221587|2022-03-23 08:48:13.845995|234.95
221588|2022-03-23 08:48:24.161308|234.31
221589|2022-03-23 08:48:34.482497|235.35
221590|2022-03-23 08:48:44.766851|233.61
221591|2022-03-23 08:48:55.082453|233.71
221592|2022-03-23 08:49:11.189965|235.9
221593|2022-03-23 08:49:21.491651|236.69
221594|2022-03-23 08:49:31.798768|237.88
221595|2022-03-23 08:49:42.122480|235.98
221596|2022-03-23 08:49:52.418405|239.38
221597|2022-03-23 08:50:02.705598|236.95
221598|2022-03-23 08:50:13.016531|237.83
221599|2022-03-23 08:50:23.308529|236.35
221600|2022-03-23 08:50:33.640350|237.57
221601|2022-03-23 08:50:43.951558|237.66
221602|2022-03-23 08:50:54.249970|237.69
221603|2022-03-23 08:51:04.578586|236.99
221604|2022-03-23 08:51:16.987639|238.63
221605|2022-03-23 08:51:27.286887|241.71
221606|2022-03-23 08:51:37.578347|237.64
221607|2022-03-23 08:51:47.852868|241.27
221608|2022-03-23 08:51:58.140011|239.93
221609|2022-03-23 08:52:10.474792|240.78
221610|2022-03-23 08:52:20.757376|240.19
221611|2022-03-23 08:52:31.076549|240.7
221612|2022-03-23 08:52:41.362319|241.28
221613|2022-03-23 08:52:51.701484|242.39
221614|2022-03-23 08:53:01.980319|241.38
221615|2022-03-23 08:53:12.310085|240.94
221616|2022-03-23 08:53:22.626300|239.68
221617|2022-03-23 08:53:32.954818|241.36
221618|2022-03-23 08:53:43.229267|238.16
221619|2022-03-23 08:53:53.513475|239.37
221620|2022-03-23 08:54:09.960105|242.23
221621|2022-03-23 08:54:20.250239|242.16
221622|2022-03-23 08:54:30.572300|240.35
221623|2022-03-23 08:54:40.886182|242.55
221624|2022-03-23 08:54:51.174385|241.62
221625|2022-03-23 08:55:01.527550|238.18
221626|2022-03-23 08:55:11.823697|238.91
221627|2022-03-23 08:55:22.313078|240.06
221628|2022-03-23 08:55:32.628169|241.03
221629|2022-03-23 08:55:42.928062|239.88
221630|2022-03-23 08:55:53.251957|240.02
221631|2022-03-23 08:56:09.494220|241.53
221632|2022-03-23 08:56:19.913754|238.12
221633|2022-03-23 08:56:30.192585|238.8
221634|2022-03-23 08:56:40.518266|242.06
221635|2022-03-23 08:56:50.804579|241.59
221636|2022-03-23 08:57:01.144732|241.47
221637|2022-03-23 08:57:12.577769|242.07
221638|2022-03-23 08:57:22.898009|240.25
221639|2022-03-23 08:57:33.241188|241.02
221640|2022-03-23 08:57:43.565434|242.64
221641|2022-03-23 08:57:53.841595|240.16
221642|2022-03-23 08:58:04.119484|239.37
221643|2022-03-23 08:58:14.410184|239.61
221644|2022-03-23 08:58:25.490278|242.89
221645|2022-03-23 08:58:35.771887|242.74
221646|2022-03-23 08:58:46.080057|239.4
221647|2022-03-23 08:58:56.363236|242.78
221648|2022-03-23 08:59:08.622582|242.2
221649|2022-03-23 08:59:18.953163|238.93
221650|2022-03-23 08:59:29.239038|241.47
221651|2022-03-23 08:59:39.570542|240.22
221652|2022-03-23 08:59:49.878068|239.12
221653|2022-03-23 09:00:00.203349|241.88
221654|2022-03-23 09:00:10.489148|242.22
221655|2022-03-23 09:00:20.767271|237.02
221656|2022-03-23 09:00:31.093296|239.62
221657|2022-03-23 09:00:41.381405|241.56
221658|2022-03-23 09:00:51.698565|240.58
221659|2022-03-23 09:01:01.979103|239.88
221660|2022-03-23 09:01:12.300760|239.97
221661|2022-03-23 09:01:22.625785|240.97
221662|2022-03-23 09:01:32.945467|239.05
221663|2022-03-23 09:01:43.269816|238.84
221664|2022-03-23 09:01:53.582686|241.5
221665|2022-03-23 09:02:08.832874|241.26
221666|2022-03-23 09:02:19.162352|242.9
221667|2022-03-23 09:02:29.486037|237.25
221668|2022-03-23 09:02:39.815679|238.96
221669|2022-03-23 09:02:50.142649|240.48
221670|2022-03-23 09:03:00.436487|237.16
221671|2022-03-23 09:03:10.761514|238.95
221672|2022-03-23 09:03:21.071955|242.4
221673|2022-03-23 09:03:31.349250|240.58
221674|2022-03-23 09:03:41.701157|242.7
221675|2022-03-23 09:03:51.982009|242.86
221676|2022-03-23 09:04:02.264601|240.27
221677|2022-03-23 09:04:12.568010|240.02
221678|2022-03-23 09:04:22.895593|241.56
221679|2022-03-23 09:04:33.195978|242.12
221680|2022-03-23 09:04:43.536890|242.99
221681|2022-03-23 09:04:53.827638|241.9
221682|2022-03-23 09:05:08.621697|239.11
221683|2022-03-23 09:05:18.905773|241.35
221684|2022-03-23 09:05:29.214875|240.41
221685|2022-03-23 09:05:39.527611|239.57
221686|2022-03-23 09:05:49.843797|238.12
221687|2022-03-23 09:06:00.141848|238.82
221688|2022-03-23 09:06:10.463252|241.17
221689|2022-03-23 09:06:21.317547|239.89
221690|2022-03-23 09:06:31.636043|238.85
221691|2022-03-23 09:06:41.985193|239.66
221692|2022-03-23 09:06:52.267225|239.58
221693|2022-03-23 09:07:02.588819|243.0
221694|2022-03-23 09:07:16.130299|241.04
221695|2022-03-23 09:07:26.404450|236.65
221696|2022-03-23 09:07:36.725877|242.23
221697|2022-03-23 09:07:47.085265|241.08
221698|2022-03-23 09:07:57.470750|242.2
221699|2022-03-23 09:08:12.828923|240.26
221700|2022-03-23 09:08:23.211681|242.27
221701|2022-03-23 09:08:33.558867|242.12
221702|2022-03-23 09:08:43.885047|241.59
221703|2022-03-23 09:08:54.242664|241.96
221704|2022-03-23 09:09:04.596579|240.26
221705|2022-03-23 09:09:15.838792|242.18
221706|2022-03-23 09:09:26.198018|242.52
221707|2022-03-23 09:09:36.533728|242.46
221708|2022-03-23 09:09:46.882959|243.61
221709|2022-03-23 09:09:57.265166|242.56
221710|2022-03-23 09:10:14.878265|241.07
221711|2022-03-23 09:10:25.228116|238.18
221712|2022-03-23 09:10:35.572799|238.79
221713|2022-03-23 09:10:45.887122|242.51
221714|2022-03-23 09:10:56.166402|243.48
221715|2022-03-23 09:11:11.600169|243.56
221716|2022-03-23 09:11:21.875800|241.99
221717|2022-03-23 09:11:32.195881|240.9
221718|2022-03-23 09:11:42.482140|242.36
221719|2022-03-23 09:11:52.774749|238.49
221720|2022-03-23 09:12:03.050786|244.42
221721|2022-03-23 09:12:13.384819|241.63
221722|2022-03-23 09:12:23.699770|238.61
221723|2022-03-23 09:12:34.020437|240.99
221724|2022-03-23 09:12:44.302949|241.04
221725|2022-03-23 09:12:54.609562|241.65
221726|2022-03-23 09:13:04.926121|241.36
221727|2022-03-23 09:13:20.313292|242.29
221728|2022-03-23 09:13:30.677382|241.13
221729|2022-03-23 09:13:41.155962|239.9
221730|2022-03-23 09:13:51.568810|241.4
221731|2022-03-23 09:14:01.958379|241.13
221732|2022-03-23 09:14:16.783782|241.59
221733|2022-03-23 09:14:27.176353|242.46
221734|2022-03-23 09:14:37.586889|241.66
221735|2022-03-23 09:14:48.035621|242.72
221736|2022-03-23 09:14:58.432423|239.19
221737|2022-03-23 09:15:08.812921|242.48
221738|2022-03-23 09:15:19.228132|242.35
221739|2022-03-23 09:15:33.088485|241.16
221740|2022-03-23 09:15:43.461496|241.41
221741|2022-03-23 09:15:53.829068|240.13
221742|2022-03-23 09:16:04.200552|243.07
221743|2022-03-23 09:16:25.372528|242.07
221744|2022-03-23 09:16:35.742537|240.83
221745|2022-03-23 09:16:46.116291|242.02
221746|2022-03-23 09:16:56.528103|238.52
221747|2022-03-23 09:17:06.937614|242.4
221748|2022-03-23 09:17:29.214212|241.48
221749|2022-03-23 09:17:39.569380|240.06
221750|2022-03-23 09:17:49.925051|243.7
221751|2022-03-23 09:18:00.314546|242.92
221752|2022-03-23 09:18:10.710766|241.34
221753|2022-03-23 09:18:28.221687|240.72
221754|2022-03-23 09:18:38.675974|240.97
221755|2022-03-23 09:18:49.072407|236.89
221756|2022-03-23 09:18:59.466969|242.03
221757|2022-03-23 09:19:09.834186|242.48
221758|2022-03-23 09:19:27.438190|242.76
221759|2022-03-23 09:19:37.865399|238.28
221760|2022-03-23 09:19:48.300233|238.22
221761|2022-03-23 09:19:58.738318|242.16
221762|2022-03-23 09:20:15.988157|243.09
221763|2022-03-23 09:20:26.446625|240.53
221764|2022-03-23 09:20:36.881158|242.83
221765|2022-03-23 09:20:47.325753|240.72
221766|2022-03-23 09:20:57.745752|242.54
221767|2022-03-23 09:21:08.130422|241.8
221768|2022-03-23 09:21:18.542783|238.78
221769|2022-03-23 09:21:34.982471|240.7
221770|2022-03-23 09:21:45.350427|240.41
221771|2022-03-23 09:21:55.703471|241.71
221772|2022-03-23 09:22:11.914038|241.96
221773|2022-03-23 09:22:22.240699|243.47
221774|2022-03-23 09:22:32.563251|243.98
221775|2022-03-23 09:22:42.895765|239.85
221776|2022-03-23 09:22:53.188993|242.17
221777|2022-03-23 09:23:08.401206|240.48
221778|2022-03-23 09:23:18.683527|239.37
221779|2022-03-23 09:23:29.012436|240.76
221780|2022-03-23 09:23:39.332266|243.1
221781|2022-03-23 09:23:49.611961|242.07
221782|2022-03-23 09:23:59.891490|241.93
221783|2022-03-23 09:24:14.154701|241.06
221784|2022-03-23 09:24:24.431753|241.35
221785|2022-03-23 09:24:34.764448|239.5
221786|2022-03-23 09:24:45.042807|239.52
221787|2022-03-23 09:24:55.352967|240.74
221788|2022-03-23 09:25:08.283903|241.21
221789|2022-03-23 09:25:18.619782|241.23
221790|2022-03-23 09:25:28.935174|240.63
221791|2022-03-23 09:25:39.262783|243.34
221792|2022-03-23 09:25:49.569143|241.38
221793|2022-03-23 09:25:59.881144|241.61
221794|2022-03-23 09:26:11.287888|244.01
221795|2022-03-23 09:26:21.686453|240.53
221796|2022-03-23 09:26:32.061271|242.87
221797|2022-03-23 09:26:42.387946|243.43
221798|2022-03-23 09:26:52.685842|242.7
221799|2022-03-23 09:27:02.996185|236.82
221800|2022-03-23 09:27:13.308467|241.49
221801|2022-03-23 09:27:27.928684|243.16
221802|2022-03-23 09:27:38.214097|240.7
221803|2022-03-23 09:27:48.500590|242.48
221804|2022-03-23 09:27:58.789643|239.35
221805|2022-03-23 09:28:09.120558|241.18
221806|2022-03-23 09:28:26.217733|241.06
221807|2022-03-23 09:28:36.768353|240.59
221808|2022-03-23 09:28:47.115654|241.28
221809|2022-03-23 09:28:57.498655|241.62
221810|2022-03-23 09:29:08.336449|241.33
221811|2022-03-23 09:29:31.780031|242.99
221812|2022-03-23 09:29:42.170203|239.42
221813|2022-03-23 09:29:52.483468|239.76
221814|2022-03-23 09:30:02.845464|242.29
221815|2022-03-23 09:30:20.455335|243.39
221816|2022-03-23 09:30:30.753419|243.37
221817|2022-03-23 09:30:41.042095|238.27
221818|2022-03-23 09:30:51.330290|241.89
221819|2022-03-23 09:31:01.661853|239.16
221820|2022-03-23 09:31:11.959550|239.87
221821|2022-03-23 09:31:23.987483|242.39
221822|2022-03-23 09:31:34.297554|242.24
221823|2022-03-23 09:31:44.801945|238.02
221824|2022-03-23 09:31:55.247081|242.28
221825|2022-03-23 09:32:10.864869|239.89
221826|2022-03-23 09:32:21.194620|244.81
221827|2022-03-23 09:32:31.526516|240.02
221828|2022-03-23 09:32:42.149504|239.03
221829|2022-03-23 09:32:52.474664|241.45
221830|2022-03-23 09:33:02.756448|238.51
221831|2022-03-23 09:33:13.165950|241.88
221832|2022-03-23 09:33:26.251531|239.12
221833|2022-03-23 09:33:36.538779|242.92
221834|2022-03-23 09:33:46.820857|243.6
221835|2022-03-23 09:33:57.103235|241.56
221836|2022-03-23 09:34:07.386125|242.41
221837|2022-03-23 09:34:20.629262|242.32
221838|2022-03-23 09:34:30.961169|242.95
221839|2022-03-23 09:34:41.241653|240.78
221840|2022-03-23 09:34:51.536036|241.69
221841|2022-03-23 09:35:01.874561|241.15
221842|2022-03-23 09:35:12.188716|239.53
221843|2022-03-23 09:35:24.873743|241.86
221844|2022-03-23 09:35:37.022633|239.89
221845|2022-03-23 09:35:47.344370|240.13
221846|2022-03-23 09:35:57.685950|242.47
221847|2022-03-23 09:36:08.013554|243.02
221848|2022-03-23 09:36:20.607524|240.52
221849|2022-03-23 09:36:30.908793|242.04
221850|2022-03-23 09:36:41.239174|241.58
221851|2022-03-23 09:36:51.564411|243.16
221852|2022-03-23 09:37:01.854305|240.7
221853|2022-03-23 09:37:12.166257|240.71
221854|2022-03-23 09:37:22.445580|239.24
221855|2022-03-23 09:37:32.775580|239.93
```

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy (completely new for me)  to select minimum value for every 15-minute period. Honestly I have no idea how to do this in plain sql not even speaking about sqlalchemy.
Can anybody give me some hints?

EDIT 1:
I think I managed to compose SQL query

```
SELECT timestamp, min(value) FROM pathloss where datetime(timestamp) >=datetime('now', '-4 Hours') group by strftime('%s',timestamp) /900;
```

but I still will appreciate any help with transforming it to sqlalchemy

EDIT 2:
added sql alchemy model setup

```
class Pathloss(db.Model):
      __tablename__ = 'pathloss'
 
      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
      timestamp = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
      value = Column(Float)
 
      def __repr__(self):
         return '<Pathloss timestamp={}, value={}>'.format(self.timestamp, self.value)
```

Comment: Can you provide the Sql alchemy data model setup for the table?

Comment: @noninertialframe I have added the model definition